# Efficient way to check more than one variable true in a conditional statement

Tags: javascript

What is the most efficient way to check more than one variable is true in a conditional statement? Please see my example below

```
var a = "Complete";
var b = "Complete";
var c = "Complete";
var d = "Complete";
var e = "Complete";

//make this more efficient
if (a == "Complete" && b == "Complete" && c == "Complete" && d == "Complete" && e == "Complete") { 
    //do something
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Efficient in what sense?

Comment: I'm assuming the OP means efficient in terms of not typing so much.

Comment: Any time you need to do the same thing with a bunch of variables, it's a clue that they probably should be an array rather than separate variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only 5 vars what you've got is probably just fine, but you could do something like this instead:

```
var isValid = [a,b,c,d,e].every(function(v) {
  return v == 'Complete';
});

if (isValid) {
  ...
}
```

The `every` method returns `true` if *all* items pass the condition, otherwise it returns `false`.